# How to define a macro only present in Visual Studio editor?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

I would like a part of the file to be present only for the editor, and be absent for c/c++ compilator. But I want to avoid using `/U` and `/D`.

```
#ifdef __VSEDITOR__
// this will be present in the editor/file but absent at compile time
#endif
```

The goal is to remove intellisense's "cannot resolve symbol" that won't be a problem at compile time (eg., with nvcc).

How can I achieve this in Visual Studio (2019) with Resharper ?

Comment: I'd personally really advise not using visual studio as there are compatibility issues with it on basically everything else you try to compile it on. That's just my preference, though.